# Linq-to-Entities/Linq-to-SQL, Is One Data Polling Method More Efficient?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Are the following two examples different and if so, which is more efficient?

```
var user = (from u in db.Users where u.Id == userId select u).Single();
```

and

```
var user = db.Users.Single(p => p.Id == userId);
```

Comment: pipe the debug info from the data context and see what queries are generated

Comment: Sql Profiler usually helps with such questions. ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are functionally equivalent. There could be slight differences in how they are implemented in the various LINQ providers, but I would expect almost exactly equal performance. The LINQ to SQL provider for example produces the exact same SQL for both queries:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name]
FROM [dbo].[User] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Id] = @p0
```

I expect that the same applies to the Entity Framework.

If I had to pick one I'd choose the second version because it is more concise with no loss of clarity. In fact I would say it is more clear - there is less keyword noise so the business logic stands out more.

Answer (score 2):

They will both wind up being identical (SQL and Efficiency wise).

Answer (score 1):

They are the same.  The compiler should produce the same outcome for both LINQ syntax.